# How to append an element inside a "<button>"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append an Icon to a button, the challenge that I am facing at the moment is that the icon retuns as a string (I see the code I wrote for the Icon).

I've tried changing qoutations marks, I've also tried putting the Icon tag inside a span and a div but it hasn't helped.

HTML code that displays the icon and carries the value the determines the icon

```
<button type="button" id="btnState" name="btnState" class="btn btn-primary btnState" value="<?php echo $pref; ?>"><?php echo "<span class='spnDash'>".$pref."</span>";?></button>
```

The code the loops though the results and selects the icon that will be displayed

```
var status = document.getElementsByClassName('btnState');
    var i;
    for(i =0; i < status.length; i++){
       var j = status[i].value;
       if(j === 1){
           $(".spnDash").remove();
           //$("<i class='far fa-thumbs-down'></i>").appendTo(".btnState");
           status[i].append('<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>');
       }
```

The Jquery code scans/checks for a value(1/0/-1) delivered from a server and then assigns an icon according to the value e.g. 1 = thumbs up, -1 = thumbs down, 0 = neutral.

Comment: Can you please post a working example of your code?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing jquery .append with javascript .append.    Try `$(status[i]).append("<i>...</i>");`

Comment: Be careful about mixing JavaScript and jQuery syntax, as it can lead to this kind of confusion. Better to choose one and stick to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status` is a DOM Collection object. You're trying to append a string to a object. Hence you're getting a string output.

You can use:

```
status[i].innerHTML+="<i class='far fa-thumbs-up'></i>";
```

Or, if you want to use append(), you have to [create a DOM object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and do as follows:

```
var obj = document.createElement("i");
obj.classList = "far fa-thumbs-up";
status[i].append(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

try using `document.getElementById('btnState')` and try not to use name attribute

Comment: There's a loop against `status.length` so there's clearly meant to be more than one button and getElementById will only get the first if the IDs are incorrectly not unique.

Comment: No worries - try again with another question :)

Comment: Feel free to still edit your answer when you think of another solution.